# Use Foreach in LIST for 2 Fields

Tags: c#, sql, list, foreach

Good afternoon again, friends;

I already have a query in SQL, where I require 2 or more fields and put them in a list.

Now, I would cross it and get the fields.

eg

**PRINT:**

Item Code: 1
Description: OIL

Item Code: 2
Description: PAPER

**OR**

**Message 1**
"CODE: 1 DESCRIPTION: OIL";

**Message 2**
"CODE: 2 DESCRIPTION: PAPER";

But with a For or Foreach, do it.

My current code:

> while (My_DataReader.Read())
>                           {
>                               if (!My_DataReader.IsDBNull(0))
>
> ```
>                             tagsList.Add(My_DataReader.GetInt32(0).ToString());
>                             tagsList.Add(My_DataReader.GetString(1));
>                     }
>
>                         MessageBox.Show(tagsList[0] + " " + tagsList[1]);
> ```

Thanked of your answers.

Best regards.

**P.D.**: *Sorry for my bad English.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < tagsList.Count; i += 2)
     Messagebox.Show(tagsList[i] + " " + tagsList[i + 1]);
```

Comment: Thanked friend. Really what I needed.

Sorry for not having positive reputation to vote.

Yours sincerely.

Comment: Ah! I had not seen: P.

At least let us close questions without reputation.

Best regards.

Happy later.